# Image cropper before uploading in laravel

Tags: image, laravel, cropper

I am looking for any library in jQuery for image crop before upload. like: http://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/ but it makes images size 6 to 7 times bigger. i.e. image of 800kb would be upload of 7mb or 8mb.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of libs to do that. Just need to google a little bit.

Some are:

https://github.com/supnate/icropper

https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs

Answer (score 0):

You should use canvas image cropper.

Answer (score 0):

[Croppie](http://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/)

```
   $uploadCrop.croppie('result', 
    {   
        type: 'canvas',
        size: 'original',
        quality:  0.7,
        format: 'jpeg',
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
With document **Image Cropper**
```

you may use it I used with laravel 5.6
http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/usage.html#styling-options